# How can I call an array of actions in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have a number of reset actions I need to fire at once. Currently I'm using a mergeMap to call the action types as below. However, I think there is a way to replace the type objects with an array of strings but I can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone help?

```
const resetModuleEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('RESET_MODULE'),
    mergeMap(() =>
      of(
        {
          type: 'RESET_IMAGE'
        },
        {
          type: 'RESET_CATEGORY'
        },
        {
          type: 'RESET_FILTERS'
        }
      )
    )
  );
```

I believe something like below is possible but can't get it right:

```
const resetModuleEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('RESET_MODULE'),
    merge(['RESET_IMAGE','RESET_CATEGORY','RESET_FILTERS'])
  );
```

Comment: What array of strings? You want to turn strings to objects or what?

Comment: @martin thanks, I updated the post. just trying to clean up the epic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example should work, probably error is somewhere else in you code.

I have added [example at stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cwyoss?devtoolsheight=60). I personally prefer `from` over `of`, but cannot reason it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have with `merge` will just take each item in the array and re-emit it so it'll output just pure strings instead of actions.

There are obviously multiple ways you can achieve what you want. For example, you can use combination of `of().map()` and turn each string into action:

```
mergeMap(() => of('RESET_IMAGE','RESET_CATEGORY','RESET_FILTERS').pipe(
  map(type => ({ type })),
))
```